# SQL Join Table - Does it require a primary key at all or just unique keys?

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp

I have created an application for the CakePHP framework which uses a join table.

I am unsure as to whether it is neccessary that I need a primary key to uniquley identify each row for the join table, as shown in the first block of SQL.

Do the two fields need to be set as unique keys or can they both be set as primary keys and I remove id as the primary key?

I was also asked why declaring atomic primary keys using a table constraint rather
than a column constraint, does this mean I shouldn't set unique keys for a join table?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories_invoices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `category_id` (`category_id`,`invoice_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=163 ;
```

I was thinking the solution is possibly to set both keys as unique and remove the primary key as shown here:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categories_invoices` (
      `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `invoice_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      UNIQUE KEY `category_id` (`category_id`,`invoice_id`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I did in fact test deleting the primary key 'id' for the join table leaving only 'category_id' and 'invoice_id' and the application still worked. This has left both fields as unique fields within the join table. Is this in fact the correct practice?

Answer (score 6):

You don't need both. The compound unique key can replace the Primary key (unless the Cake framework cannot deal with compound Priamry Keys):

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories_invoices (
      category_id int(11) NOT NULL,
      invoice_id int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (category_id, invoice_id)
    ) 
    ENGINE = MyISAM 
    DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 ;
```

---

It's also good to have another index, with the reverse order, besides the index created for the Primary Key:

```
   INDEX (invoice_id, category_id)
```

---

If you want to define Foreign Key constraints, you should use the `InnoDB` engine. With `MyISAM` you can't have Foreign Keys. So, it would be:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories_invoices (
      category_id int(11) NOT NULL,
      invoice_id int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (category_id, invoice_id),
      INDEX invoice_category_index (invoice_id, category_id)
    ) 
    ENGINE = InnoDB  
    DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

---

If Cake cannot cope with composite Primary Keys:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS categories_invoices (
      id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      category_id int(11) NOT NULL,
      invoice_id int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      UNIQUE KEY category_invoice_unique (category_id, invoice_id),
      INDEX invoice_category_index (invoice_id, category_id)
    ) 
    ENGINE = InnoDB  
    DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

Comment: CakePHP does not support composite primary keys. If you want to directly manipulate your join table the documentation states I should add a primary key. However I do not have the requirment for this, so the SQL you have provided is the correct solution? To delcare both fields of the join table as primary keys?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the second method.  It is referred to as a composite key and is very common in database design, especially in your circumstance.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#Primary_keys

Comment: CakePHP does not support composite primary keys. So for this join table should both `category_id` and `invoice_id` be declared as a Primary Key?